# Why mat-icon doesn't look good in mat-chips on Firefox Browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, angular-material, angular9

I tried to make auto-complete input with mat-chip in Material Design. In this situation, I am using official [Angular manual](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview) or [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dgnmdonbvpr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-input-example.ts) on website. Everythings works, everything looks good as it's supposed to be on Google Chrome and also Opera browsers but chips' `matChipRemove` looks weird on Firefox browser. I shared images on browsers for better understanding.

*Google Chrome / Opera Browser (Nicely)*

[image: Mat-Icon looks good on Google Chrome browser]

*Firefox Browser (Weird. There is a box behind icon.)*

[image: Mat-Icon looks weird on Firefox browser]

How does the code that works well in Google Chrome/Opera does not work in Firefox? What is causing this problem?

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?